# How to delete all detail block when i delete master block oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreign-keys, master-detail, oracleforms

When I delete a record from the Master Block it should delete all records in the Block Details .... but this does not happen with me ... This message appears "frm-40510: ORACLE error unable to DELETE record".

I pressed `shift + f1` this message appears:

SQL statement in error: `DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ROWID=:1`

error `ORA-02292: integrity constraint (schemaName.C_NO_FK) violated - child record found`.

this is my delete button code

```sql
DECLARE
   v_id      NUMBER := :CUSTOMERS.C_NO;
   v_alert   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('CUSTOMERS.C_NO', enabled, property_true);
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('CUSTOMERS.C_NO', update_allowed, property_true);
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('CUSTOMERS.C_NO', navigable, property_true);

   IF v_id IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      v_alert := SHOW_ALERT ('DEL_ALERT');

      IF v_alert = alert_button1
      THEN
         GO_BLOCK ('CUSTOMERS');
         DELETE_RECORD;
         :SYSTEM.message_level := 25;
         COMMIT;
         :SYSTEM.message_level := 0;
         MESSAGE ('deleted');
      END IF;
   ELSE
      MESSAGE ('choose one record to delete it');
      MESSAGE ('choose one record to delete it');
      GO_ITEM ('btnsrch');
   END IF;
   GO_ITEM ('btnsrch');
   SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('CUSTOMERS.C_NO', enabled, property_false);

   exception when others then
    message(sqlerrm);
END;
```

I want to use `delete_record;` instead of delete statement `delete form detailTable where …`

then `delete form masterTable where …….` this is works fine but not `delete_record;`

Comment: your code is correct there is nothing about it.. but you need to change Relation properties   Delete Record Behavior to cascading. that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple just go to Relations in master block and press F4 and Set "Delete Record Behavior" property to "Cascading".

Comment: thank you for your answer. where can I find Relations in that master block?